# Counting inversions in an array of 2D pair

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Problem Description:
Let there be an array of 2D pairs ((x1, y1), . . . ,(xn, yn))
. With a **fixed** constant
y' a pair (i, j) is called half-inverted if i < j, xi > xj , and yi ≥ y' > yj . Devise an algorithm
that counts the number of half-inverted pairs. You will get full marks if your algorithm is
correct of complexity no more than O(n log n).
\My idea is to treat this using similar method as counting inversion in a normal array, but my problem is that how do we maintain the order during the Merge And Count step?

Comment: you should be able to use the mergesort algorithm to count the inversions as you would usually do, but you bring satellite data (using a matrix and moving both colums at the same time), then in the merge when you check for the inversion you also check if the Y[i,1]>Y'>Y[j,1] in that case you add 1 to your counter

Comment: imagine that on the image here https://www.techiedelight.com/merge-sort/ you also have a second array below the one you got and you order using the top one but check using the second one

Comment: Hi phil, I'm especially confused since we cannot be sure that y is in order. How could we do the comparison (merge and count) in O(n) time?

Comment: @Skin_phil Hi phil, I'm especially confused since we cannot be sure that y is in order. How could we do the comparison (merge and count) in O(n) time?

Comment: i suggest you take a good look at the merge algorithm and then just do the same steps you do to the first array( the X array) to the second (Y array)

Comment: if you carry the y as satellite you don't care about its order you just want to compare it when you compare the xs

Comment: @Skin_phil So the idea is to sort according to x value? I don't understand what you mwan by taking y as a satelite part. Could you explain a little more? Maybe we could talk via email. Mine is zw1806@nyu.edu. Thank you!

Comment: @Skin_phil Hi phil, here's my interpretation: we maintain the order of both x and y in the merge step, that is the x and y do not have to stay in their original pair.

Comment: no, read your title: a pair (i, j) is called half-inverted if i < j, xi > xj , and yi ≥ y' > yj, your elements are couples, you cannot separate x and y, the point of merging only the X and carrying the Y with it is that you don't care if that is not ordered, bc in the case x is not ordered the first condition is false: thus not needing the y check

Comment: I would try to do it myself but i really don't have enough time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple modification of the familiar merge-sort inversion counting algorithm which can be used to solve this problem so make you fully understand it as a prerequisite.

If we examine the merge step of this algorithm we have 2 sorted halves and 2 pointers pointing to an element of each. Let our left pointer be `i` and our right, `j`. Using the traditional definition of an inversion, if our `i` pointer points to a value that is larger than the value pointed to by `j` then due the arrays being sorted and all the elements on the left being before those on the right in the real array, we know all the elements from `i` to the end of the left half meet our definition of an inversion for our value at `j` so we increase our count by `mid - i` where `mid` is the end of the left half.

Switching back to your problem, we are dealing with pairs `(x,y)`. If we can keep our `x` values sorted then, using the approach described above, we can simply count the number of inversions only considering `x` values. Looking at your definition of half inversions we will surely be over counting the number we need if we only count `xi > xj`. We are missing the additional constraint of `yi >= y' > yj` which must be filtered out of our counting.

So, if we look back to our traditional algorithm when our `i` pointer is pointing to a value greater than the value at `j` we **also** need to make sure that our `y` value at `j` is less than `y'`. If this not true then none of the `x`'s from `i` to `mid` will match our definition of a half inversion and so we cannot count them. Now let's assume our `j`'s `y` is smaller than `y'`, if we simply counted all the pairs from `i` to `mid` then we would still be over counting the pairs which have `yi < y'`.

One way to fix this is to keep track of the of `y` values in the left half from `i` to `mid` which are `>= y'` and add that value to our count. We can keep track of how many `y >= y'` we see in the merge step up to any `i`, and subtract that from the total number of `y`'s which are `>= y'` in the left half. To keep track of that total number we can return that value from our recursive function (total = left + right) and only use the number which came from the left half when merging. We also need to modify our base case which is straightforward.

```python
def count_half_inversions(l, y):
    return count_rec(l, 0, len(l), l.copy(), y)[0]

def count_rec(l, begin, end, copy, y):
    if end-begin <= 1:
        # we have only 1 pair
        return (0, 1 if l[begin][1] >= y else 0)
    mid = begin + ((end-begin) // 2)
    left = count_rec(copy, begin, mid, l, y)
    right = count_rec(copy, mid, end, l, y)
    between = merge_count(l, begin, mid, end, copy, left[1], y)
    # return (inversion count, number of pairs, (i,j), with j >= y)
    return (left[0] + right[0] + between, left[1] + right[1])

def merge_count(l, begin, mid, end, copy, left_y_count, y):
    result = 0
    i,j = begin, mid
    k = begin
    while i < mid and j < end:
        if copy[i][0] > copy[j][0]:
            if y > copy[j][1]:
                result += left_y_count
            smaller = copy[j]
            j += 1
        else:
            if copy[i][1] >= y:
                left_y_count -= 1
            smaller = copy[i]
            i += 1
        l[k] = smaller
        k += 1
    while i < mid:
        l[k] = copy[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1
    while j < end:
        l[k] = copy[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1
    return result
                
test_case = [(1,1), (6,4), (6,3), (1,2), (1,2), (3,3), (6,2), (0,1)]
fixed_y = 2

print(count_half_inversions(test_case, fixed_y))
```

Comment: Thank you! I came up with a solution similar with yours. Tricky question :).